# Improving user experience in Windows Forms Client that has low internet speed and uses a WCF web-service hosted far away

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

I have a live WCF service hosted in US. I want to access it from a Windows Forms application that can be used from anywhere in the whole world. Currently I am testing it in India and trying to access my US hosted web-service. This application can be used from any connection speed and at any distance from the server. So speed of response from the server may vary. What I decided is that when user performs some function, my application will first update the UI and then it will perform the server update task in background. This will prevent the application from freezing or hanging. Following is one of these scenarios. But the problem is that even I am using Asynchronous functions and threads to update UI and server, the application is still freezing.

Actually I have a button that acts as a toggle between like and unlike. When a user clicks it, it should change to unlike and then it runs a thread that updates the server in background. Following is the code for the Button's click event:

```
async private void btnLike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(changeLike)).Start();
      await LikeContent();
}
```

`changeLike` function:

```
private void changeLike()
{
     if(btnLike.Text.Equals("Like"))
             btnLike.Text="Unlike";
     else
             btnLike.Text="Like";
}
```

`LikeContent` function:

```
async Task<int> LikeContent()
{
      await Global.getServiceClient().addContentLikeAsync(cid, uid);

      System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(reloadLikes));
      t.Start();
      return 0;
}
```

`addContentLikeAsync()` function is a WCF web-service function that updates user likes on server.
`reloadLikes()` updates the number of likes from the server after user liked the content.

Please tell me how can I modify my code so that application instantly updates the LIKE button instead of freezing for some time and then updating the LIKE button? Because this "sometime" will create a bad impression on users having less internet speed.

Comment: Your `changeLike()` is not suitable for a thread, are you sure this runs OK?

Comment: Why are you calling `changeLike()` on a new thread? Just call it directly.

Comment: Creating threads should be avoided in favour of `ThreadPool` and `Tasks` unless you need a dedicated thread for the job. You do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I assume the `btnLike_Click` method is called on the UI thread. In this case, do not call `changeLike()` on a separate thread.

```
async private void btnLike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      changeLike();
      await LikeContent();
}
```

Second, be sure to marshal back to the UI thread before `reloadLikes()`

```
async Task<int> LikeContent()
{
      await Global.getServiceClient().addContentLikeAsync(cid, uid);

      // Ensures this occurs on the UI thread - WinForms
      Invoke((Action)reloadLikes);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChapel. I modified my code according to your code. Its working great. Thanks :)